# Looking for ateji for Colombia

Tags: meaning, kanji, names, ateji

My mother's name is Colombia (like the country) and I'm trying to give her a gift because she loves the Japanese landscapes (like trees or combinations of red, black and white). I want to write her name in a correct way and explain to her in a simple words. On the Internet I found 哥倫比亜.
(https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%93%A5%E5%80%AB%E6%AF%94%E4%BA%9C#Japanese) But reading books and trying to understand the correct way is hard and maybe this web page could help me.
I ask a person in a congress and she wrote this on paper and its very different. I tried to search for information but maybe I don't have the correct path or sites for this information.

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you think Wikitionary is wrong?

Comment: You could use Katakana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

哥倫比亜 is an [ateji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ateji) country name for Columbia. It was created many years ago to write Columbia in kanji, but ordinary Japanese people today do not use nor understand 哥倫比亜. Well, each kanji is not so difficult, so it makes sense as a quiz (i.e., "Which country does this refer to?").

- [What’s your country’s name in traditional Japanese ateji?](https://deadreckoning8.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/whats-your-countrys-name-in-traditional-japanese-ateji/)
- [The logic behind kanji choice for country name ateji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24295/5010)

By nature, there are theoretically thousands of possible ways to write Columbia using ateji. The image you pasted reads 古呂ン美阿 written vertically. That's another possible way to write Columbia using ateji, but I don't think it's an orthodox one. I got nothing related to Columbia by googling with 古呂ン美阿. (Artistically speaking, it's well written, though.)

If your mother loves kanji and you really need to use kanji for Columbia, perhaps 哥倫比亜 would be the normal choice.

Answer (score 1):

Country names are nowadays usually written in *katakana* although the *ateji* do feature in abbreviations, where usually the first character of the *ateji* is used. (A well-known exception being 米 from 亜**米**利加 because 亜 had already been used for 亜細亜【アジア】.)

In case of Colombia, Wikipedia actually lists [many *ateji*](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%BD%E5%90%8D%E3%81%AE%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E8%A1%A8%E8%A8%98%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7):

- 哥倫比亜
- 哥倫比
- 可倫比亜
- 哥倫米阿
- 閣龍比亜
- 古倫比亜
- 可侖比亜
- 古論備亜
- 戈攬弥阿
- 古論備屋
- 科倫比亜

However, of these only the first one appears in most of the sources.

If you are not going to write the country's name, then you're not expected to use the most common *ateji* for the country.

There are names whose *kanji* are chosen like *ateji*. But none of the above candidates look like a woman's name (which is not surprising!).